# Countdowntimer cancel crashes the app when click on button

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I am trying to create a *countDownTimer* but, whenever I click on the button the app crashes.
I want that if I click on *player1* button *player2 countdown* should pause and vice versa for *player2*.

**The Error I am getting:**

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.os.CountDownTimer.cancel()' on a null object reference

**Here is the Code**

```
public class Timer extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button player1, player2;
    long incrementTime = 3000;
    int time;
    long timeinLong;
    ImageButton pause;
    CountDownTimer player1count, player2count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

        player1 = findViewById(R.id.player1);
        player2 = findViewById(R.id.player2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);
        timeinLong = time * 60000;

        int minutes = (int) (timeinLong / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (timeinLong / 1000) % 60;

        String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        player1.setText(timeFormatted);
        player1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCountDown(player1);
                player2count.cancel();

            }
        });
        player2.setText(timeFormatted);
        player2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCountDown2(player2);
                player1count.cancel();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startCountDown(final Button button) {
        player1count = new CountDownTimer(timeinLong, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeinLong = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText(button);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeinLong = 0;
                updateCountDownText(button);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void startCountDown2(final Button button) {
        player2count = new CountDownTimer(timeinLong, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeinLong = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText(button);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeinLong = 0;
                updateCountDownText(button);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText(Button button) {
        int minutes = (int) (timeinLong / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (timeinLong / 1000) % 60;

        String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        button.setText(timeFormatted);

        if (timeinLong < 30000) {
            button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (player1count != null) {
            player1count.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: player2count will be null untill you click player2 button. If you click player1 button before clicking player2 button the player2count will be null/not initialized. So it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player2count` only gets initialized inside `startCountDown2`, which is only called inside `player2.setOnClickListener`. Hence, if you click on the `player1` button before ever clicking on `player2` button, you'll get a `NullPointerException`, since calling `player2count.cancel()` on a not-yet-initialized `player2count` is not allowed. To prevent this from happening, it would be appropriate to just check for null in this case:

```
if (player2count != null) {
  player2count.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't initialize that when click listener called
i fixed it for myself by add try catch on .cancel lines
or set

```
if (player1count != null)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't cancel timers unless they're intialized, it will bring NPE, so check if they're not null in both players as below

```
    player1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCountDown(player1);
            if (player2count != null)
                player2count.cancel();

        }
    });
    player2.setText(timeFormatted);
    player2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCountDown2(player2);
            if (player1count != null)
                player1count.cancel();
        }
    });
```